# How to prevent double quotes being escaped when importing data from a text file into a hive table

Tags: hive

I have this datatype info map and if I select this field in hive console, the result would look something like this

{"a":"value1","b":"value2"}.

How do I represent this data in a text file so that when I import it to the hive table, it is properly represented. I mean should my text file should have something like this ?

a:value1,b:value2

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load JSON documents in Hive? There are serde's available to load and query JSON data in hive.

In your case, "a" and "b" would become column names (header)